# SQL Server 2008: I'm trying to do an update with in a if statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wrote a SQL query to do an update to a column with in an `IF` statement. The query uses the `if` statement to determine whether the column meets the right condition and if it does it proceeds to update the column.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it executes with:

> Command(s) completed successfully.

But when I look at my table the update has not been applied...

I'm still new to SQL.

```
DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50)

IF @Status = 'Active Debtor'
BEGIN
   UPDATE Table1
   SET Col1 = 'Pre-Legal'
   FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON CM_IDX = DB_IDX
   WHERE TypeID = 1
     AND Col1 = @Status
END
```

Comment: If that's your entire code then `@Status` is never assigned a value - how did you expect it to acquire a non-NULL value?

Comment: it means that you have nothing to update that's whats happening try to check your where clause, an update will just execute commands successfully if no rows are updated, if it updates a row it will show how many rows are affected

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't assigned a value for your `DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50)` 
it should have an value to enter the IF

```
IF @Status = 'Active Debtor'
```

the code above returns false because of the null value of @Status
making it exit the program returning Commands succesfully, an update with updated rows shows how many rows would be affected.